# "onchange" & "oninput" event listeners not working for my input type range, javascript html css

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('.weather-slider')

  // EVENT LISTENERS
  slider.addEventListener('oninput',(e)=>{
    console.log(slider);
  })
```

```html
    <input type="range" class="weather-slider"
     value="1" min="1" max="168" step="2">
```

Here's the full code on codepen

```
https://codepen.io/userahmad2001/pen/vYdwKmW
```

The desired result:
I want the **onchange,oninput** function to trigger when the value of the range slider changes, However the function isn't working and there doesn't seem to be any problems, the console is also empty.

Comment: You should use `change` and `input` instead of the `on...` variants which are usually reserved for HTML attributes to bind the listeners. See the [change event documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `change` and/or `input` eventhandlers instead

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('.weather-slider')

  // EVENT LISTENERS
  slider.addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
    console.log('change');
  });
  
    slider.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
    console.log('input');
  });
```

```html
<input type="range" class="weather-slider"
     value="1" min="1" max="168" step="2">
```